# HIVEQL select all accounts for a given customer who has AT LEAST ONE account that satisfies a certain criteria

Tags: hive, hiveql

So i have a large dataset that contains credit card accounts. A customer can have multiple credit card accounts. So the accounts is unique, the customer is most certainly not unique (customer '1234' can have 5 accounts). I want to select a customer's entire account list if any of the accounts satisfy a particular requirement. The requirement is looking at its last cycle date (when the account last cycled). so let's look at this dataset...

```
account|customer|last_cycle_dt
4839|1|20190114
9522|1|20190103
1195|1|20181227
5461|2|20190112
1178|2|20190108
2229|2|20181218
8723|3|20181227
5692|3|20181227
0392|4|20190113
1847|5|20190113
0389|5|20190112
3281|5|20190101
2008|5|20181222
3948|5|20181216
```

So i have this data sorted in a particular way that it's easier to see. In fact maybe the data needs to be sorted this way to do the extract (most efficiently) but I'm not sure.

So the criteria in our extract will select all customers accounts who has at least 1 account who's last_cyc_dt field is GREATER THAN 20180112

So...
We would select ALL of customers 1 accounts 
We would select NONE of customers 2 accounts
We would select NONE of customers 3 accounts
We would select ALL of customers 4 accounts
We would select ALL of customers 5 accounts

Because there exists at least 1 account for that customer who's last cycle date is greater than 20180112

What's the best approach to achieve this in HIVE ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `max` as a window function, get the latest last_cycl_dt for each `customer` and check if it is greater than the required date.

```
select account,customer,last_cycl_dt
from (select t.*,max(last_cycle_dt) over(partition by customer) as latest_last_cycl_dt
      from tbl t
     ) t
where latest_last_cycl_dt > '20180112'
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying to do this in a scala shell session and getting an out of memory error. How can I limit this so that I don't get this error. When i add a "limit 50" at the end of table a and table b it's saying my syntax is wrong. Basically i just want to pull 50 rows from the first table (a) and another 50 from the second table (b) and then go from there. Even putting the limit on the end of the select statement it give out of memory cause it's doing the initial inner join on a and b with the entire population....

Comment: val df2=spark.sql("select acct_ref_nb,entp_prty_id,last_cyc_dt from (select t.*,max(last_cyc_dt) over(partition by entp_prty_id) as latest_last_cycl_dt from (select a.acct_ref_nb,a.last_cyc_dt,b.entp_prty_id from sz_ccb_ccs_risk.CEMS_DAY_ACCT a inner join sz_ccb_ccs_risk.CEMS_DAY_CUST_ACCT_CARD b on(a.acct_ref_nb = b.acct_ref_nb)) t) where latest_last_cycl_dt > '20180112'")

Comment: I was able to code it in java and run the query using a spark submit command. This way I didn't get the error. I'm seeing now the above command is not working. I can clearly see a customer who has multiple accounts and one of them is greater than the latest_last_cycl_dt value but it's not pulling in all of those customers accounts. It's almost as if ALL accounts need to be greater than that value and that's not what I'm looking for. Only if one or more satisfies then select ALL accounts.

Comment: What do i need to include in my class in order for this to work?